# OCaml type binding in recursive modules

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to build a sequence of recursive modules in ocaml. Here is a minimally simple example:

```
  module rec Foo : sig
    type t =
      | A of int
      | B of Foo.t
  end = struct
    type t =
      | A of int
      | B of Foo.t
  end       

  module rec Bar : sig
    open Foo
    type map_t = int -> Foo.t
    type t = { foo : map_t }
    val bar_of_foo : Foo.t -> t
  end = struct
    open Foo

    let rec bar_of_foo f = match f with
      | A a -> let ff (_:int) = a in 
               { Bar.foo = ff }
      | B b -> { foo = bar_of_foo b.foo } 
  end
```

Compilation fails in function `bar_of_foo`, in the match of A, with `Error: unbound type constructor f`.

I don't understand why this is happening - field `foo` is defined as having type `map_t = int -> Foo.t`, and `f` has signature `int -> Foo.t`.

I've also tried simply referring to record field `foo` as `foo` rather than `Bar.foo` (in the match case for `B` - that gives me an `Errror: unbound record field foo` error).

Any pointers or advice gratefully received.

Steve

Comment: (1) The innermost `f` (the outermost `f` being a parameter to `bar_of_foo`) has signature `int -> int`, since it uses  `a : int` as its return value. I think it's a good idea to remove the name clash.

(2) I fail to see recursive dependencies between `Foo` and `Bar`. I just see that `Bar` uses `Foo`, but  not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Name clash removed in post.

Comment: OK, so what I don't understand is how the typing is resolving in `bar_of_foo`. The first line: ` | A a -> let ff (_:int) = a in { Bar.foo = ff }`
starts by matching with type `A` ( = `Foo.A`). And, the type of `Foo.A` is `int`. So I understand why the signature of `ff` is `int -> int`. 

But A is one of the variants of `Foo.t`, so why can `bar_of_foo` not have signature `Foo.t -> int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since `bar_of_foo` is a function it has type `x -> y`.
2. The type inference algorithm sees that you pattern-match the argument `f` on the constructors of `Foo.t`. This fact fixes `x = Foo.t`.
3. When you return `{foo = ...}` the system gets `y = Bar.t` (or just `t` in our context).
4. So, `bar_of_foo : Foo.t -> Bar.t`.

The following code compiles and it is similar to the code in the OP:

```
module Foo : sig
  type t =
  | A of int
  | B of t
  end = struct
  type t =
      | A of int
      | B of t
  end

module Bar : sig
  type map_t = int -> Foo.t
  type t = { foo : map_t }
  val bar_of_foo : Foo.t -> t
  end = struct
    open Foo

    type map_t = int -> Foo.t
    type t = { foo : map_t }

    let rec bar_of_foo f = match f with
      | A a -> { foo = fun (_:int) -> A a }
      | B b -> bar_of_foo b 
  end
```

A test:

```
open Foo
open Bar

let () =
  let bar = bar_of_foo (B (B (B (A 42)))) in
  match (bar.foo 0) with
    | A n -> print_int n; print_newline ()
    | B _ -> print_string "Impossible!\n"
```

And the output:

```
$ ocaml example.ml
$ 42
```

Note that the modules `Foo` and `Bar` are not mutually-recursive. Otherwise we would have to write

```
module rec Foo : sig
  ...
  end = struct
  ...
  end
and Bar : sig
  ...
  end = struct
    ... 
  end
```

Comment: Ha! I just finally worked it out for myself, and was in the middle of answering my own question when you beat me too it. Thank you very much for your help - you and camlpost helped me get there :-)

Comment: And a very nice clear exposition of the type reasoning :-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is now redundant since the things pointed here are reflected to the question.

Syntax errors in your record expressions.  Use `=` not `:`, i.e. `{ Bar.foo = f }` and `{ foo = bar_of_foo b }`.

After that, your code has still some typing issues.  For example, `bar_of_foo b` has type `t` therefore it cannot be used as a `foo` member of `t`.